# Can not Create pair - constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, std-pair

I can not create a pair when one of the classes in the pair in a `class Edge`
I know it is because of the constructors in Edge, but I do not know what is wrong.

The Edge constructor has a `Token` because I wanted to make sure that only an Object of type `Vertex`
can create an object `Edge`.

```
class Edge
{
public:
   class ConstructionToken
   {
   private:
      ConstructionToken();
      friend class Vertex;
   };

   Edge( const Edge &) = default;
   Edge( const ConstructionToken & ){};

private
   //weight, etc...
};

void
Vertex::insert_edge( const std::string & end_point )
{
   Edge new_edge( Edge::ConstructionToken );
   std::pair<std::string,Edge> temp( end_point, new_edge );
   //edges.insert( temp );


}
```

Compiling error

```
lib/Vertex.cpp:12:32: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::pair<std::string, Edge>'
   std::pair<std::string,Edge> temp( end_point, new_edge );
                               ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:262:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion
      from 'Edge (Edge::ConstructionToken)' to 'const Edge' for 2nd argument
    pair(const _T1& __x, const _T2& __y)
```

Comment: use `std::make_pair`.

Comment: @101010: That would just move the error to the point at which the deduced pair type is converted to `pair<string,Edge>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
Edge new_edge( Edge::ConstructionToken );
```

declares a function, since the name in parentheses is a type. To declare a variable, use

```
Edge new_edge{ Edge::ConstructionToken{} };  // C++11 or later
Edge new_edge((Edge::ConstructionToken())); // Historic dialects
```

Comment: Beat me to it! :) Most Vexing Parse?

Comment: @Component10: Yes, some people call it that.

Comment: @Component10 I think the *most* vexing parse is the obvious but flawed "solution" to this particular case: `Edge new_edge(Edge::ConstructionToken());`, but the term is often used for less vexing parses as well.

Comment: for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse
I was not aware of this. cool.